# More concise methods for wrapping a file than using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

**Introduction**

*script:*

```
sed -i '1i <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>' $1
sed -i '/<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>/a<hello>\n\t<world>' $1
sed -i "\$a\\\t<\/hello>\n<\/world>" $1
```

*input:*

```
<city id="city01">
  <name>utrecht</author>
  <population>328.577</population>
  <districts>10</districts>
  <country>netherlands</country>
</city>
```

*output:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hello>
  <world>
    <city id="city01">
      <name>utrecht</author>
      <population>328.577</population>
      <districts>10</districts>
      <country>netherlands</country>
    </city>
  </hello>
</world>
```

**Question**

What are more concise methods for wrapping a file than using sed?

Comment: What do you mean by one of the most concise? Sure it is. For example, it is certainly one of the 100 most concise methods. Is the particular approach you are using _the_ most concise? No. Are you asking for more concise methods? Are you asking for commentary on this approach? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to first insert a line and then look for this line instead of inserting two lines. You can escape newlines in `i` commands and you can group commands with `{}`. Your approach would make sense only if it was possible that the searched for line appears several times.

Comment: @terdon The question has been updated.

Comment: Your produced XML is not well-formed: take care to close your tags in the opposite order to opened them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I don't understand what your actual question is. Here are some more concise ways of doing what your `sed` script does:

```sh
$ printf "%s\n%s\n\t%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' \
'<hello>' '<world>' "$(cat file)" "</world>" "</hello>"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hello>
    <world>
<city id="city01">
  <name>utrecht</author>
  <population>328.577</population>
  <districts>10</districts>
  <country>netherlands</country>
</city>
</world>
</hello>
```

or

```sh
$ echo -e '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' "\n<hello>\n<world>" "$(cat file)" \
"</world>\n</hello>"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<hello>
<world> <city id="city01">
  <name>utrecht</author>
  <population>328.577</population>
  <districts>10</districts>
  <country>netherlands</country>
</city> </world>
</hello>
```

or

```perl
$ perl -lpe 'BEGIN{
            print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<hello>\n\t<world>"
            } 
            $_="\t\t$_"; END{print "\t </world>\n</hello>"}' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hello>
    <world>
        <city id="city01">
          <name>utrecht</author>
          <population>328.577</population>
          <districts>10</districts>
          <country>netherlands</country>
        </city>
     </world>
</hello>
```

You can edit the file in place with `perl -i -ple`.

or

```awk
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<hello>\n\t<world>";} 
        {print "\t\t",$0}END{printf "\t </world>\n</hello>\n"}' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hello>
    <world>      <city id="city01">
           <name>utrecht</author>
           <population>328.577</population>
           <districts>10</districts>
           <country>netherlands</country>
         </city>
     </world>
</hello>
```

or a mixture:

```
$ echo -e '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<hello>\n\t<world>'; 
  perl -pe '$_="\t\t$_"' file; echo -e "</world>\n</hello>"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hello>
    <world>
        <city id="city01">
          <name>utrecht</author>
          <population>328.577</population>
          <districts>10</districts>
          <country>netherlands</country>
        </city>
</world>
</hello>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the more concise methods for wrapping a file than using sed. I have used the awk method `sudo awk 'BEGIN{printf "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<hello>\n\t<world>\n";} {print "\t\t",$0}END{printf "\t </world>\n</hello>\n"}' hello > hello2` and this works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not more concise, but perhaps more readable:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
cat <<END >$tmp && mv $tmp "$1"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hello>
    <world>
        $(sed 's/^/        /' "$1")
    </world>
</hello>
END
```

Comment: Nice to think of indents. I would indent with `pr -tro 6`.

Comment: You are missing $a, the sed command should be `$(echo "$a"|sed 's/^/      /')`

Comment: Why would I need to do that? What do you think `$a` is? The `$a` in the question is not a variable, it is a sed address (`$`, the last line) and a command (`a`, append)

Comment: You are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v indentchar=$'\t' \
'BEGIN { print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"; print "<hello>"; 
print indentchar "<world>";};
{ print indentchar indentchar $0; };
END { print indentchar "</world>"; print "</hello>"; }' file
```

Comment: +1, but why is indentchar worth it? Why not just `print "\t<world>";` and `print `"\t\t"$0`? etc?

Comment: @terdon I did so first but then I noticed that the questioner used `\t` but the example output looked more like two spaces to me. Thus I offered a solution which can be easily modified.

Answer (score 1):

Given a fixed start (written in the file xml_head) and end of the output (xml_tail)
and a variable $a:

```
cat xml_head;echo "$a"; cat xml_tail
```

You could also make a template xml_file with ===a=== in the middle:

```
cat xml_template | sed 's/===a===/'$a'/'
```

However, the last solution will fail when you have new lines in $a.

Actually, the input is not given in the variable $a, but it is the input/output file.
The solution should be something like

```
mv ${file} ${file}.org && \
(cat xml_head && pr -tro 6 ${file}.org && cat xml_tail) > ${file} && rm ${file}.org
```

Comment: +1 Definitely my favorite solution. For a one-off version, you can use `cat <<HEAD contents_file <<TAIL` and use two heredocs.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  rm -f -- "$1" &&
  {
    printf '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<hello>\n\t<world>\n'
    paste /dev/null -
    printf '\t</hello>\n</world>\n'
  } > "$1"
} < "$1"
```

Would be more portable, efficient and readable, if not shorter.